# putback fails for stringstream while adding extra char

Tags: c++, stringstream, istream

I have following code snippet to modify the stringstream such that it will have additional one char infront. But, i couldn't get the expected result.

```
void modifyStream(std::istream& s1)
{
    if (s1.putback('Y'))
       std::cout << s1.rdbuf() << '\n';
    else
       std::cout << "putback failed\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  const char* str = "Hello, world";
  std::stringstream s1(str); // IO stream
  modifyStream(s1);

  return 0;
}
```

> Output: putback failed

But, i am expecting the output of "YHello, world".
Can someone help to resolve this?

Comment: The function putback doesn't return a boolean but a pointer. You can however encapsulate your call in a try catch block and look for the exception "failure" that it will throw.

Comment: @zoubida13 no, `putback` does not return a pointer. It returns a reference to the input stream which is convertible to a boolean. Encapsulating in a try catch won't do anything unless the call throws something, which was not observed here.

Comment: I didn't say it would solve the problem, otherwise I would have posted an answer, I am just commenting on the use of the implicit casting when you can have a nice exception that tells you why it failed. And fyi what you call the reference to the input stream is, in fact, a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a misunderstanding about the [`putback`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback) method in your code: Its purpose is not to *prepend* data to the stream but to replace one **already** extracted character with another (you do not add anything, you replace an old character with something new). This is a bit more understandable by reading the documentation of [`sputbackc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sputbackc) which is called by `putback`.

Example (from [encppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback)):

```
std::stringstream s1("Hello, world"); // IO stream
s1.get();
if (s1.putback('Y')) // modifies the buffer
    std::cout << s1.rdbuf() << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "putback failed\n";
```

Output:

```
Yello, world
```

The call `s1.putback('Y')` puts the character `'Y'` back at the place of the last extracted character (in this case `'H'`).

Comment: Yes that's correct!. But I noted that putback() was able to prepend the data to the stream when it is istream object. But it fails when it comes to stringstream. Is there any other way to cast the stringstream into istream so that it can prepend the data to the stream?

Comment: @Karthick I don't really get you - Could you show the code that work with `istream`?

Comment: I made following changes to main funciton.                                                           int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  modifyStream(cin);

  return 0;
}                                                                                                            Created a text file called test.txt with the content "Hello, world". Run the program TestProgram.exe < test.txt which printed output as "YHello, world"

Comment: @Karthick My last comment was a bit wrong so I removed it. The behavior of `putback` depends on `pbackfail` which default behavior (in `streambuf`) is to prepend the character (if not `eof`), but this behavior is overridden by [`stringbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/pbackfail). If you really want to prepend to a stringstream, you will need to create a new one and add whatever you want to it.